# Rails4: Why is 'created_at DESC' appended　automatically? How do I remove it?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Althogh I'd like to order records by average rating of articles, `ORDER BY created_at DESC` was appended automatically when I checked `development.log`.

Why is this condition appended? How can I remove it?

.schema articles

```
CREATE TABLE "articles" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "content" text(400), "user_id" integer, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime,"category_id" integer, "rating" real);
CREATE INDEX "index_articles_on_user_id_and_created_at" ON "articles" ("user_id", "created_at");
```

\model\category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles
    ...
end
```

\model\article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
    ...
end
```

\controllers\category_controller.rb

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @articles = Article.select('*, AVG(rating) AS avg_rate').group(:category_id).order('avg_rate DESC')
  end

    ...

end
```

\log\development.log
**ORDER BY created_at DESC** was appended.

```
Processing by CategoriesController#index as HTML
  [1m[36mArticle Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT *, AVG(rating) AS avg_rate FROM "articles" GROUP BY category_id ORDER BY created_at DESC, avg_rate DESC[0m
....
```

Comment: Could you please provide all article.rb?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @maxd. I found the `default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }` exists when I check article.rb again.

Comment: lol was just gonna ask if u have a default scope, guess u found it, kinda one of the reasons why i hate default scopes

Comment: ``default_scope`` is **evil**

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `default_scope` but don't want it for a particular query alone use `unscoped` in the query. Example:

```
Article.unscoped.select('*, AVG(rating) AS avg_rate').group(:category_id).order('avg_rate DESC')
```